# Memory-mapped I/O address ranges

Tags: bus, addressing

In Memory-mapped I/O, how does device allocation and address ranges are decided? For instance like, EPROM has control over address bus for address from > 0x0000 and <0x4000, RAM1 from 0x4000 to 0x8000
Especially curious about partial address decoding methods

Comment: Re "The thing is that i am supposed to design decoder logic and trying to get how this is done. ANd I will not accept the method of using random logic gates" - You need to better explain your REAL question. eg "I have an assignment that asks ...". People here are not going to do your assignment for you (if that is what this is) BUT will happily help you if they know the real question.

Comment: The real question is to write logic for entities that are connected to the common data bus, so i am just trzing to get the full picture understanding separate parts of it

Comment: IS that the real question? Who used those words? | At the moment it's still wholly unclear what your real need is. Any problem of this sort is liable to be trivial in concept and may or may not be easy in practice. When you decide to tell us what you actually want we'll be able to help. "Logic for entities" sounds great enough until you try and tie it with certainty to a real need.

Comment: here is the figure from Tanenbaums book 'structured computer organization' http://ubinomad.site88.net/photo.JPG  | So I was wondering how the decoder is constructed.. Cannot make my question more precise

Comment: Well, the answer is in black and white in front of you in the form of those pictures.  Combinations of logic gates which cause the CS line of a specific chip to go low when certain ranges of addresses are placed on the address bus.

Comment: You can convert those images into logic tables if you like.  You would have 16 inputs and one output - maybe with intermediate outputs and inputs if there are multiple gates.  Take the EEPROM in the second example.  The inputs would be in the form of xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx0 or xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx1 (the EEPROM is only linked to A15 so the others are "don't care") to give an output of 0 or 1 respectively (the simplest example possible - no gates).  That equates to a memory range of 0x0000 to 0x7FFF.

Comment: How it is implemented in the "real world" is often inside a CPLD or similar custom chip - the Spectrum I mention in my answer has a custom "ULA" (Uncommitted Logic Array) chip that does the job - but internally they are just collections of logic gates.

Comment: Yes, this is the answer that i needed, thank you very much for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure address decoding logic.

The upper bits of the address bus are routed through logic, usually including things like '3-to-8 decoder' and the like to create a selection of "chip select" signals that connect to the different devices to activate them at different address ranges.

So for your example, the upper 2 bits of address bus could be linked to a 2-to-4 decoder to give the ranges 0x0000 to 0x3FFF, 0x4000 to 0x7FFF, 0x8000 to 0xBFFF and 0xC000 to 0xFFFF

The lower 14 bits will all be connected direct to all the devices (or as many as they need up to 14)

Within those ranges you could further split it down if you desired to make a finer-grained range.

Comment: how can i find out if the decoding logic uses full address decoding or partial decoding?

Comment: In general it will be partial if you are working with "blocks" of memory.  For peripherals at specific addresses it may be a combination of partial and full - partial to select the block the peripheral is in, then full decoding within that block to determine the exact peripheral address.  Sometimes they get lazy and only do partial within the block, so the peripheral is actually available on multiple addresses.

Comment: The thing is that i am supposed to design decoder logic and trying to get how this is done. ANd I will not accept the method of using random logic gates

Answer (score 2):

Memory address mappings are largely the result of decisions made by processor manufacturers. Users can distribute memory sparsely within the appropriate address spaces but users usually "go with the flow" and do what processor hardware requires.

For example, if a processor fetches powerup and reset vectors from, say, the bottom of memory the users must arrange for program memory containing the vectors to be at those locations during startup.

In your example, EPROM (or other program memory) was probably at 0x0000 because the processor looked at a location at or near x0000 for its startup vector.

It is less common but some systems move banks of memory around to meet specific needs. For example, a processor may have low address startup and interupt vectors but also have an instruction set that favours instructions that address a small block of memory near 0x0000. For example, the instruction set may allow 4 or 6 bits of immediate address to be carried within the instruction word allowing efficient addressing of the first 16 or first 64 bytes of memory. In such a case, startup may require ROM low but efficient use of instructions may require RAM low. Both can be achieved by eg setting address line 6 of the EPROM low during startup and setting it high subsequently, thereby moving the EPROM memory block up by 64 or whatever positions. Similarly RAM is moved into 0x0000 area. If other interupt vectors are contained in low address space these need to be written to the RAM prior to it being moved downwards.

---

Address decoders can be arranged to do almost anything desired with address lines and with what goes where. A memory block may be repeated N times, or appear only once, or may have only half appear at a time with the control of which half appears being controlled by an I/O bit.

Comment: how can i find out if the decoding logic uses full address decoding or partial decoding?

Answer (score 1):

One approach which hasn't yet been mentioned is to give half of the address space to the biggest device, possibly give half of what is left to the next biggest, and then divvy up the remainder.  A lot of devices have multiple chip-select pins; sometimes they conveniently have some active-high and some active-low.  Suppose, for example, one was designing a 6502-based system with a 16-bit address bus which needed a 16Kx8 ROM, a 32Kx8 RAM, and eight I/O devices that need 256 bytes or less each.  One could feed A15 directly to the chip-select for the RAM, use a single NAND gate (!(A15 & A14)) to generate a chip-select for the ROM (or else use a mask ROM with two active-high chip selects), and use a 74HC138 to generate the I/O device chip-selects, feeding A15 to an active-high enable and A14 into an active-low enable.  Using this approach avoids any need to 'or' together multiple outputs from the 74HC138 to handle devices that require more than 1/8 of the address space.

A number of interesting legacy devices actually manage to avoid using any discrete logic for address decoding.  For example, the Atari 2600 has a 13-bit address space mapped as follows:

```
1 xxxx xxxx xxxx -- Cartridge (external)
0 xx1x 1xxn nnnn -- RIOT I/O registers
0 xx0x 1nnn nnnn -- RIOT RAM
0 xxxx 0xnn nnnn -- TIA (Television Interface Adapter) registers
```

The RIOT chip (RAM/IO/Timer) has active-low and active-high chip selects, wired to A12 and A7, respectively, and a RAM/IO select line, wired to A9.  The TIA has two active-low chip selects wired to A12 and A7.  Cartridges typically use a mask ROM with an active-high chip select.  The system thus selects among the four categories of address space without any discrete logic chips.

Answer (score 1):

Unclear if it is what you mean by "partial" decoding, but there is a scheme which I would call "incomplete" decoding.

If you have a processor with more address lines providing a larger address space than you actually need, you can simply ignore some of them for some purposes.  In the simplest case, you can take a high order address line and use that (possibly inverted) as a chip select.  A device so selected will appear over and over again many times in the address space of the processor, but as long as the one of those mappings you use in the software doesn't overlap the mapping of anything else, you are okay.

Another form of this was to take something like the 74LS138 3-to-8 decoder which generates 8 chip select outputs from 3 address line inputs and a few active high and low enables.  You wire that up to give you 8 blocks of memory ranges of the size required by your largest peripheral and dedicate one to each peripheral.  Many of your peripherals likely don't need as large a block as the largest peripheral did, and so will have their memory mapped registers repeat several times within it.

Answer (score 0):

For higher end micros, the decoding logic is internal to the microcontroller. It allows you to configure a range of address for some devices. For example, you can define a range of address for an external FLASH, another range of addresses for external SRAM and another for a the LCD controller.

Answer (score 0):

The ranges actually change according to the maker and designer of the chip. Some part of these ranges are sometimes kept for hardware programming purposes. You can find more information on this in R S Gaonkar's [8085 Microprocessors book](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Microprocessor_Architecture_Programming.html?id=b1YGAAAACAAJ&redir_esc=y).